# "Manage" menu item does not work (64-bit Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, windows

My *manage* menu stopped working (I suspect Windows Updates caused this problem).

[image: manage menu]

I get this error when it is clicked:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try re-running the Windows updates.  In the history you may be able to select "Service Pack 1" to be re-installed which may also help to resolve this problem.

My guess is that your computer may have lost power during the recent updates, and the file needed for this function didn't get installed properly (or at all) as a result of this interruption (if not power loss, a crash or reset button usage could effectively cause the same problem).

Comment: Whoever is voting down this response, I'd like to know what the reason is -- my answer provides a solution that could actually help to resolve the problem.

Comment: @Randolf Richardson - wasn't me, your ideas are valid IMO.

Comment: @techie007:  Thanks for that.  I like your commentary in other questions/answers too (and I'm laughing at the picture in your profile right now, heheh)!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try using [Windows' System Restore](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-CA/windows7/products/features/system-restore) to go back to a point before the problem arose.

If all seems OK after going back, then re-apply the updates one at a time to determine which one (if any) causes the problem.

Comment: One note of caution with System Restore:  Backup your data before you run this.  Although System Restore is generally very useful for problems like this, I have had reports from users who tried to use it and lost some of their recent documents and spreadsheets.